# Using the OFFSET excel function in VBA .formula error

Tags: vba, excel-formula, offset

I'm trying to use the function OFFSET in a cells.formula and it returns me an erros 1004. I know that the formula work if I use it directly without macro

`.Cells(5, c_write).Formula = "=MIN(OFFSET(data!" & Split(.Cells(1, c_read).Address, "$")(1) & "3;0;0;data_calc!" & .Cells(3, c_write + 1).Address & "))"`

I tried with other formulas as MIN or COUNTA and it worked fine, but with OFFSET, it put an error 1004

Comment: need to use `,` instead of `;` when using `.Formula`

Comment: Also the concatenation does not make sense.  try printing the text string before setting it to the cell: `Debug.Print "=MIN(OFFSET(data!" & Split(.Cells(1, c_read).Address, "$")(1) & "3;0;0;data_calc!" & .Cells(3, c_write + 1).Address & "))"` and make sure the text looks correct and can be pasted into a cell.

Comment: so it was the coma indeed. Yes I tried doing a `MsgBox' of the string and it was correct. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ctrl+G will open the Immediate pane in the Visual Basic Editor if it's not already open - `Debug.Print` results appear in there.  You can also type/copy paste  `?"=MIN(OFFSET(data!" & Split(.Cells(1, c_read).Address, "$")(1) & "3;0;0;data_calc!" & .Cells(3, c_write + 1).Address & "))"` directly in there.  Easier than creating a MsgBox. :)